# How to make a vertical, collapsible menu in GWT?

Tags: java, eclipse, gwt, menu

Alright, check my code:

```
public MainForm() {

        HorizontalPanel horizontalPanel = new HorizontalPanel();
        initWidget(horizontalPanel);

        VerticalPanel verticalPanel = new VerticalPanel();
        horizontalPanel.add(verticalPanel);

        MenuBar menuBar = new MenuBar(true);
        verticalPanel.add(menuBar);
        MenuBar menuBar_1 = new MenuBar(true);

        MenuItem mntmNewMenu = new MenuItem("General", false, menuBar_1);

        MenuItem mntmBuilding = new MenuItem("Building", false, (Command) null);
        menuBar_1.addItem(mntmBuilding);

        MenuItem mntmModularBuilding = new MenuItem("Modular Building", false, (Command) null);
        menuBar_1.addItem(mntmModularBuilding);
        menuBar.addItem(mntmNewMenu);
        MenuBar menuBar_2 = new MenuBar(true);

        MenuItem mntmNewMenu_1 = new MenuItem("New menu", false, menuBar_2);
        mntmNewMenu_1.setHTML("EPC");
        menuBar.addItem(mntmNewMenu_1); //target
        MenuBar menuBar_3 = new MenuBar(true);

        MenuItem mntmNewMenu_2 = new MenuItem("New menu", false, menuBar_3);
        mntmNewMenu_2.setHTML("Constructions");
        menuBar.addItem(mntmNewMenu_2);
        MenuBar menuBar_4 = new MenuBar(true);

        MenuItem mntmRecommendations = new MenuItem("Recommendations", false, menuBar_4);
        menuBar.addItem(mntmRecommendations);

    }
```

At the moment, the sub menu with Building and Modular Building options is coming out to the side. How can I change the code so that the sub menus appear below the menu bar selections? Some styling to show that they were sub menus would be helpful also.

Thank ya very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `StackPanel` for this purpose. Please see the showcase here : http://gwt.google.com/samples/Showcase/Showcase.html#!CwStackPanel

I hope this will be helpful.

Comment: Or [StackLayoutPanel](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.0/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/StackLayoutPanel.html) if the OP is in standards mode.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Weird that the link you gave wasn't on my Google results. Thank you!